# Caching concern for Next.js App on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I've deployed a Next.js app to AWS Amplify. The app uses getServerSideProps to fetch data from an api. The api is a REST api using a lambda function that connects to PostgreSQL RDS instance. Afterhours, the RDS instance is shutdown and the api returns a timeout when I try to connect to it.

My concern is that data is still showing in the app after hours. While not the worst, I'm more concerned about it being stale data and it being used for decision making. How is this possible? I'm assuming there is a cache, but I can't determine what part of the app is doing the caching (is it AWS Amplify or Next.js)?

Comment: If anyone else runs into this issue, the assets are stored in CloudFront and remain there for 24 hours by default. For me, I received a 503 error after the time expired.